# Where to find shp2pgsql windows binaries?

Tags: postgis

Is there anywhere available shp2pgsql binaries for windows without installing the whole PostGIS? I particularity need the command line version of that import tool.

I would like to share a batch script that uses the shp2pgsql.exe to my co-workers but don't know how to share the shp2pgsql.exe. Could I just copy that file from my postgres/bin folder? I suppose that then I need at least libpg.dll. How about other files (libgdal-1.dll, libproj.dll)?

Comment: may be useful for you http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.postgis/3080

Comment: Thanks @Sunil, but didn't help. That thread was from 2004 and linked to unknown zip file that doesn't exists. And ogr2ogr doesn't work in my case.

Comment: We are researching on your issue..and let you know soon

Comment: Its working @ my end http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/

Comment: Use depend.exe to find what libraries it depends on. I think libconv might be the only one.

Comment: Thanks @Sunil and @Paul! I downloaded the binaries in zip file and used depend.exe to find out the crucial dlls. Shp2pgsql needs only the libiconv-2.dll. Psgl I got from pgAdmin installation. That depends on libpq.dll, libintl.dll and ssleay32.dll.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answering to my own question based on help from @Sunil and @Paul.

Shp2pgsql.exe is available in binary download from http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows.  It comes with a lot of unnecessary files. Only libiconv-2.dll in needed.

To be able to load shapes to PostGIS also the psql.exe is needed. It comes with pgAdmin installation. It depends on libpq.dll, libintl.dll and ssleay32.dll.

Comment: Thanks, small update for the current version of shp2pgsql. Additional files required: libgcc_s_seh-1.dll, libgeos.dll, libgeos_c.dll, libproj-9.dll, libstdc++-6.dll. Also libintl.dll is now libintl-8.dll.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure how long it's been available, but if you download the ZIP bundle from the link above, it contains a GUI for the Shapefile <--> PostGIS import/export in \bin\postgisgui.

Works like a charm, and no installation required!