# PostGIS without shp2pgsql

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, shp2pgsql

I recently reinstalled PostGIS on my pc, following
these instructions [link](http://technobytz.com/install-postgis-postgresql-9-3-ubuntu.html).
The installation is successful, and for several days work using PostgreSQL and PostGIS without problems.
Now, I need to insert some shapefile within my database, but trying to execute the command "shp2pgsql" I get this result:

```
abominio@abominio-X555LD:~$ shp2pgsql --help
Il programma "shp2pgsql" non è attualmente installato.
È possibile   installarlo digitando: sudo apt-get install postgis
```

I tried to do a search

```
sudo find / -name shp2pgsql
```

but I do not get results.
currently I'm using Postgres 9.3 and PostGIS 2.1.6.
why I do not have this function? how can I fix?

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to make a link under /usr/bin/shp2postgres  to  ../lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/shp2pgsql with the right permission.

Comment: try this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50107/where-to-find-shp2pgsql-windows-binaries